# Free Windows Application Blocker/Monitor

Tags: software-rec, monitoring, blocking

I want a free application monitor that when it detects certain keywords on window title for example, it closes the application (or prevents that it opens/installs).

Nice extra will be if the program logs the application activity and internet sites accessed by any browser.

PS: I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2):

you could write some [autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/downloads.shtml) scripts,

```
$WindowsTitle = 'Some Window Title'

While 1
    If WinExists( $WindowsTitle ) Then
        ProcessClose(WinGetProcess( $WindowsTitle))
    EndIf
    Sleep(10) 
WEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [RescueTime](http://www.rescuetime.com/) does most of this.